# How to get value of the cell under the current cell with Google Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I can't find an option that could look like

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet(); 
sheet.getRange(sheet.getCurrentCell() + 1,1).getValue())
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding, you want to get the value of the cell below the current cell (+1 row of the current cell).

### OPTION 1:

You can modify your current code like this:

```
sheet.getRange(sheet.getCurrentCell().getRow() + 1,1).getValue()
```

You need to get the row index of the current cell first using [Range.getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow), then increment it by 1.

---

### OPTION 2:

You can use [Range.offset(rowOffset, columnOffset)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset) to go into the next row then get its value using [Range.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)

**Sample Sheet:**

[image]

**Sample Code:**

```
function myFunction(){

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()
  Logger.log(sheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1,0).getValue());
}
```

**Output:**

[image]